# How can I set up my Django function to run in the background from button onclick?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, background-process, pythonanywhere

I have a Django project and one of the functions currently runs onclick of my html -

```
def follow(request):

    api = get_api(request)

    followers = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, wait_on_rate_limit=True).items()

    for x in followers:
        try:
            api.create_friendship(x)
        except Exception:
            pass

    return render(request, "followed.html")
```

The function runs and follows the followers of the authorised user. My issue is that when deployed on my pythonanywhere web app the function will load in the browser and then timeout after around 10 minutes. I have tested on users up to 100 followers and it all works.

This would be fine but the Twitter API has a rate limit and so for some users who have large followings this function will take a long time to complete.

Is there a way of diverting to the followed.html and keeping the function running in the background until it is completed?

I have added the oauth functions just in case they are needed too -

```
def auth(request):
    # start the OAuth process, set up a handler with our details
    oauth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    # direct the user to the authentication url
    # if user is logged-in and authorized then transparently goto the callback URL
    auth_url = oauth.get_authorization_url(True)
    response = HttpResponseRedirect(auth_url)
    # store the request token
    request.session['request_token'] = oauth.request_token
    return response

def callback(request):
    verifier = request.GET.get('oauth_verifier')
    oauth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    token = request.session.get('request_token')
    # remove the request token now we don't need it
    request.session.delete('request_token')
    oauth.request_token = token
    # get the access token and store
    try:
        oauth.get_access_token(verifier)
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        print('Error, failed to get access token')

    request.session['access_key_tw'] = oauth.access_token
    request.session['access_secret_tw'] = oauth.access_token_secret
    print(request.session['access_key_tw'])
    print(request.session['access_secret_tw'])
    response = HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    return response
```

Comment: Take a look at https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at using a task queue to do work in the background. In general, doing any work that is "blocking" while handling a HTTP request (eg something makes your server wait, such as connecting to another server and getting data) should be done as a background task.

Common (and good!) Python task queues are [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) and [rq](https://python-rq.org/) - rq is particularly lightweight and also has a Django wrapper [django-rq](https://github.com/rq/django-rq)

I'd spend a bit of time reading the rq or Celery docs to get an idea of how to make your Twitter API calls happen as background tasks, which will avoid your web server timing out.

Comment: https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ as Miles Davis mentioned looks pretty cool, too

Comment: I love django-q because for tiny applications you can use django orm as broker (and you get admin models for queued, successful, scheduled and failed task too!) so it can work with zero configuration. No need to configure redis or rabbit etc.

Install, add to installed_app in django, set 'orm' as broker in settings, migrate and you're ready. Pretty cool.

Comment: Nice! I like that you can choose a different broker other than redis while still getting a lightweight implementation. I'll def try it the next time I need a queue

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at Django Q. I had seen celery when searching myself for an answer but PythonAnywhere does not allow it. I may look at deploying it on Heroku too, make my life a little easier

Answer (score 0):

You can use an asynchronous task queue (e.g. celery) for this. take a look at this:
https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/